# When a Service delegates data retrieval to a Data Mapper, which one should return a Model?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, datamapper

I have set up a basic architecture, in which a Service delegates the retrieval of data to a Data Mapper (pseudocode below).

```
ProductService->fetchById(123);

class ProductService
{
    public function fetchById(id)
    {
        product = ProductMapper->fetch('id', id);
        // or product = new Product(ProductMapper->fetch('id', id)) ?
        return product;
    }
}

class ProductMapper
{
    public function fetch(bySomething, value)
    {
        // fetch stuff from DB.
        // return new Product or just raw data? 
    }
}
```

What is the best practice here if I want to end up with, let's say, a ProductCollection, or a Product?

- Should the Data Mapper create instances of these Models and return them to the Service, which passes them along to the Actor?
- Or should the Data Mapper give raw data to the Service, which then instantiates Models with that data before passing them to the caller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is the responsibility of the data access code to convert a raw data query I.e. SQL into an object. What would the DataMapper be mapping if it didn't return an object?

I'm not clear why you need a service at all though here - what is it for? Could you not just do something like

var theObject = theDataAccessThing.get(someId)

[UPDATE]

If the service has logic I'd structure the code (example in C#) something like:

```
public class OrderService
{
    private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;
    public OrderService(IOrderRepository repository){
        _orderRepository= repository
    }

    public void ApplyDiscount(orderId){
        var order = _orderRepository.Get(orderId);
        order.ApplyDiscount();
        _orderRepository.Save(order);
    }
}
```

or statically:

```
public static class OrderService
{
    public static void ApplyDiscount(IOrderRepository orderRepository, int someOrderId) 
    {
        var order = orderRepository.Get(orderId);
        order.ApplyDiscount();
        orderRepository.Save(order);
    }
}
```

This makes it easy to test, as well as allowing you to change what the underlying implementation of IOrderRepository is as you see fit.

Comment: I'd like to keep the service as an abstraction. The Data Access Layer could be retrieving data from ElasticSearch, or from a SQL database, or from whatever other source. With the Service as an abstraction, I could easily switch data sources later on without having to refactor too high up in the code.

Comment: That sounds like the Repository pattern rather than what I would consider a service. For me, the repository would encapsulate the data access code whereas a Service would actually have business logic / behaviour associated with it. https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/03/ddd-repository-implementation-patterns/

Comment: Well, the service _would_ have some logic. Let's say, for instance 
`order = OrderService->fetch(123); 
OrderService->applyDiscount(order); 
OrderService->persist(order)`. 
Would you consider this repository behaviour?

Comment: I'd consider Loading and Saving the object repository behaviour, but the concept of applying a discount would belong on the object (aka in the domain) - please see updated answer